# compound index/searching on child array

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, nosql

Based on the data below, I'm looking to do something like "find block 1 where the parent objects name is 'Panel'"

So, I tried setting up a compound index like this:

```
objStore.createIndex('by_name_and_block', ['Name', 'blocks.Name']);
```

And then calling it (sort-of) like this:

```
var index = objStore.index("by_name_and_block");

var request = index.get("Panel", "1");

// I've also tried:
// var request = index.get(["Panel","1"]);
...
```

But this doesn't work.  Is there a way to set up this compound index in **indexeddb**?

Sample data:

```
[
    {
        Name: "Post",
        blocks: [
            {
                Name:"1",
                Arrays:[]
            },
            {
                Name:"2",
                Arrays:[]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: "Panel",
        blocks: [
            {
                Name:"1",
                Arrays:[]
            },
            {
                Name:"2",
                Arrays:[]
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Good point, I was doing it as you put it in the first example, but it makes sense that wouldn't work.  I switched it to the second example and now I'm getting `DataError`

Comment: Your question is not clear for me.

Comment: How can I help make it more clear @OrtomalaLokni?  For example, I want to get one object, where, say `block.Name = "2"` and the parent object `Name = "Panel"` -- in the example above, I would get the the 2nd block object of the second parent object.  In SQL, `SELECT * FROM Parent JOIN Blocks <<on some criteria>> WHERE parent.Name = 'Panel' and blocks.Name = '1'`

Comment: I have been looking at this and I think that the definition of the 2nd part of the keypath is incorrect.  According to the data model shown, "blocks" is an array.  In order to address an item in that array, you need to specify a vector.  e.g.: blocks[0].Name.  This does not seem like what you really want, so perhaps the datastore design needs to be revisited.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not able to index with current specification. See [steps for extracting key from keyPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#steps-to-assign-a-key-to-a-value-using-a-key-path). Notice that object is not valid key value in array key path.

In v2, you will be able to use with index function expression.

Currently, you will have to generate extra variable before you persist into the database and remove it after retrieval. Use multiEntry index without compound index.

Answer (score 0):

Is this script that what you want?

```
var obj = [
    {
        Name: "Post",
        blocks: [
            {
                Name:"1",
                Arrays:[]
            },
            {
                Name:"2",
                Arrays:[]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: "Panel",
        blocks: [
            {
                Name:"1",
                Arrays:[]
            },
            {
                Name:"2",
                Arrays:[]
            },
        ]
    },
];

function getBlockByName(objName, index){
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        if(obj[i].Name == objName)
            return obj[i].blocks[index];
    }

    return false;
}

//Index starting from 0
console.log(getBlockByName("Panel", 1));
//Will return {Name:"2", Arrays:[]} object
```

Comment: Well, not really.  I'm looking to do this with [IndexedDb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) -- that obj is actually a **huge** object, so just holding it in memory and cursoring through it is not going to work.